# How can I efficiently calculate differences between values of a column and the preceding column in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the differences between values of a column and the values from a preceding column for each row, for example:

```
    1   2   3   
R1. 50 60. 90
R2. 80.95. 115
R3. 90 100 120
```

I would want the code to do the following:
(values in col 2 - values in col 1), (values in col 3 - values in col 2), (values in col 4 - values in col 3), etc..

for an output that would store the calculated values in a new table like this:

```
    1   2      
R1. 10 30. 
R2. 10.20 
R3. 10 20
```

I've been doing this manually on a small set of columns as follows, but is there a code to more efficiently do this on a larger set of columns/rows

```
#to calculate differences
diff_new = tab_new[,2] - tab_new[,1]
diff_new2 = tab_new[,3] - tab_new[,2]
diff_new3 = tab_new[,4] - tab_new[,3]
diff_new4 = tab_new[,5] - tab_new[,4]

#to create a new table with differences
diff.table_new = cbind(diff_new,diff_new2,diff_new3,diff_new4)
```

Answer (score 3):

One base R option would be

```
df[-1] - df[-ncol(df)] # thanks @user20650
```

Output

```
    X2 X3
R1. 10 30
R2. 15 20
R3. 10 20
```

Or use `sapply`:

```
sapply(seq_len(ncol(df))[-1], function(x) df[,x] - df[,x-1])
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   30
[2,]   15   20
[3,]   10   20
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "1   2   3   
R1. 50 60 90
R2. 80 95 115
R3. 90 100 120", h = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

`diff` with a lag:

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "    1   2   3   
R1. 50 60 90
R2. 80 95 115
R3. 90 100 120")

matrix(diff(unlist(df), lag=nrow(df)), nrow=nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fully vectorized option:

```r
data.frame(t(diff(t(df))))
```

---

You can use `apply` + `diff`:

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "    1   2   3   
R1. 50 60 90
R2. 80 95 115
R3. 90 100 120")

t(apply(df, 1, diff))

#    X2 X3
#R1. 10 30
#R2. 15 20
#R3. 10 20
```

Comment: Why do you need `apply`? Just `t(diff(t(df)))` should work

Comment: Right, `t` already converts to matrix

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution using `data.table` and `collapse` as long as your data doesn't have `NA` values.

Here we make a copy of the original data (except for the 1st col) and modify the columns by reference.

```r
library(data.table)
library(collapse)
# Take a copy
out <- copy(fselect(df, -1))

# Subtract lagged columns by reference
for (i in seq_col(out)){
  out[[i]] %-=% df[[i]]
}
out
#>     X2 X3
#> R1. 10 30
#> R2. 15 20
#> R3. 10 20
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## Data

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "    1   2   3   
R1. 50 60 90
R2. 80 95 115
R3. 90 100 120")
```